# "field jdoFieldFlags is conflicting" when using @MappedSuperclass on GAE/J & JPA

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus, mappedsuperclass

I got an error when querying to the entity extended by mappedsuperclass on GAE/J.

**MappedSuperClass**

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractModel {

    private String lastModifiedBy;
    private Timestamp createTimestamp;
    private Timestamp modifyTimestamp;
    private Integer version;

    // setters & getters
}
```

**Entity**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class EmployeeModel extends AbstractModel {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String address;
    private String name;
    private String position;

    // setters & getters
}
```

JPA query is like below.

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE", EmployeeModel.class);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<EmployeeModel> list = q.getResultList();
```

And I got the error

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Result Class query field names are not case sensitive. It does not allow fields with same name, but in a different case. For instance, the field "jdoFieldFlags" is conflicting.
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:302)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAQuery.getResultList(JPAQuery.java:202)
    at test20140919.EmployeeDao.list(EmployeeDao.java:21)
    at test20140919.EmployeeLogic.list(EmployeeLogic.java:34)
    at test20140919.EmployeeAction.list(EmployeeAction.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:160)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Result Class query field names are not case sensitive. It does not allow fields with same name, but in a different case. For instance, the field "jdoFieldFlags" is conflicting.
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ResultClassROF.populateDeclaredFieldsForUserType(ResultClassROF.java:508)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ResultClassROF.populateDeclaredFieldsForUserType(ResultClassROF.java:514)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ResultClassROF.access$100(ResultClassROF.java:65)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ResultClassROF$1.run(ResultClassROF.java:228)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ResultClassROF.<init>(ResultClassROF.java:224)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.RDBMSQueryUtils.getResultObjectFactoryForNoCandidateClass(RDBMSQueryUtils.java:532)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.SQLQuery.performExecute(SQLQuery.java:295)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1789)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractSQLQuery.executeWithMap(AbstractSQLQuery.java:345)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAQuery.getResultList(JPAQuery.java:185)
    ... 48 more
```

The message says "the field jdoFieldFlags is conflicting.", but any fields are not duplicated and I don't define jdoFieldFlags field.

Why this error happens? and please tell me how to solve this error.

Defining all the field in EmployeeModel and not extend AbstractModel can remove this error.
But I want to avoid this solution because fields in AbstractModel are common to all the tables in my application.

[Update] App Engine version is 1.9.11, and storage is cloudSQL. Table definition is as below.

```
CREATE TABLE `EMPLOYEE` (
  `address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `position` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastModifiedBy` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `createTimestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modifyTimestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `version` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**[Update2]**
I have updated DataNucleus to version 4.0.2, but similar error happens. I don't have duplicate field and dnFieldFlags.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Result Class query field names are not case sensitive. It does not allow fields with same name, but in a different case. For instance, the field "dnFieldFlags" is conflicting.
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:308)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAQuery.getResultList(JPAQuery.java:213)
    at (my app : List<class with inheritance> list = q.getResultList();)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:160)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Result Class query field names are not case sensitive. It does not allow fields with same name, but in a different case. For instance, the field "dnFieldFlags" is conflicting.
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ResultClassROF.populateDeclaredFieldsForUserType(ResultClassROF.java:507)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ResultClassROF.populateDeclaredFieldsForUserType(ResultClassROF.java:512)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ResultClassROF.access$100(ResultClassROF.java:65)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ResultClassROF$1.run(ResultClassROF.java:225)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.ResultClassROF.<init>(ResultClassROF.java:221)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.RDBMSQueryUtils.getResultObjectFactoryForNoCandidateClass(RDBMSQueryUtils.java:547)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.SQLQuery.performExecute(SQLQuery.java:289)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1840)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractSQLQuery.executeWithMap(AbstractSQLQuery.java:356)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAQuery.getResultList(JPAQuery.java:197)
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: define what is your datastore? and the versions of the software involved?

Comment: I have updated my post. Please refer to [Update] section.

Comment: And the versions of the DataNucleus jars? (assuming you're using DataNucleus for JPA) And if not using v4.0 please state why not

Comment: DataNucleus version is 3.1.3, because App Engine 1.9.11 has this version.

Comment: AppEngine "comes with" that version because it is the only one that works with its own datastore "GAE/Datastore" (which you aren't using). You are using Cloud SQL so can use the latest versions

Comment: I will try the newest version 4.0.2.

Comment: you could also try not having inheritance in the result class, since the JPA spec doesn't mention about having to allow that when dumping SQL results into a result class (just of providing Java bean style result classes)

Comment: I tried with DataNucleus 4.0.3 and all works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tryed EclipseLink. Above codes works fine.