# Datanucleus v4 with GAE

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, datanucleus

I'm developping an application with GAE/Datanucleus/cloudSQL.

Datanucelus version is 3.1.3 because newest App Engine SDK (1.9.11) includes this version, but I was advised to use Datanucleus v4 [in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25904674/field-jdofieldflags-is-conflicting-when-using-mappedsuperclass-on-gae-j-jpa)

I removed 3.1.3 jars from war/WEB-INF/lib and added 4.0.2 jars to the same folder. When I run the application, it seems working well.

But eclipse is complaining errors as belows.

```
The App Engine SDK JAR datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.3.jar is missing in the WEB-INF/lib directory
The App Engine SDK JAR datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar is missing in the WEB-INF/lib directory
The App Engine SDK JAR datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.3.jar is missing in the WEB-INF/lib directory
```

If I add the 3.1.3 to war/WEB-INF/lib, eclipse error has gone, but application fails because of multiple JAR versions.

Can anybody tell me the straightforward way to use Datanucleus v4 with GAE?

Comment: and what is complaining? Google's Eclipse plugin? Configure it to use the right versions (assuming it allows that)?

Comment: Eclipse problems tabs says errors. I can't find how to specify the versions. DN 3.1.3 is specified in Properties -> java build path -> Libraries -> App Engine SDK, but I can't edit the version from eclipse. Changing the files from explorer may work, but I don't know if this is the straightforward way to change the version.

Comment: See this page https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appengine_datanucleus which says "use DataNucleus JDO/JPA to access the datastore" ? Well untick it because that is GAE/Datastore - not that Google's plugin tells you. Or better still you just use the DATANUCLEUS eclipse plugin, since they wrote it to work with their software

Comment: Untick "use DataNucleus JDO/JPA to access the datastore" and add 4.0.2 jars to java build path looks fine. Errors on eclipse have gone and application seems working. Thanks.

Comment: Good. added as an answer so you can accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this page](http://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appengine_datanucleus) which says "use DataNucleus JDO/JPA to access the datastore" ? Well untick it because that is GAE/Datastore - not that Google's plugin tells you. Then put whatever jars you need for your JPA implementation into the CLASSPATH and all should be fine.